# SSIS script task not executing outside SSDT

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I created a SSIS script task which reads data from excel sheets and saves it into different tables in SQL Server DB. When I execute the SSIS package inside Visual Studio SSDT it works fine.

When I am trying to execute my SSIS package from C# .NET code I get the following error.

> Error in Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.TaskHost/Script Task : There was an exception while loading Script
> Task from XML: System.Exception: The Script Task "ST_71d9425916264171ab93a0d340aad54d" uses version 14.0 script
> that is not supported in this release of Integration Services. To run the package, use the Script task to create
> a new VSTA script. In most cases, scripts are converted automatically to use a supported version,when you open a
> SQL Server Integration Services packages in %SQL_Product_Short_Name% Integrtion Services.

I tried to change the deployment version by changing the TargetServerVersion to SQL server 2016 but I still get the same error.

Here is my code to execute the package.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace Execute_DriverImpact
{
    class MyEventListener : DefaultEvents
    {
        public override bool OnError(DtsObject source, int errorCode, string subComponent,
          string description, string helpFile, int helpContext, string idofInterfaceWithError)
        {
            // Add application-specific diagnostics here.  
            Console.WriteLine("Error in {0}/{1} : {2}", source, subComponent, description);
            return false;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The code provided will print ‘Hello World’ to the console.
            // Press Ctrl+F5 (or go to Debug > Start Without Debugging) to run your app.
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            //Console.ReadKey();

            //ExecuteSSIS exec = new ExecuteSSIS();
            //exec.ExePackage();

            //ExecuteSSIS2 exec = new ExecuteSSIS2();
            //exec.ExePackage2();

            string pkgLocation;
            Package pkg;
            Application app;
            DTSExecResult pkgResults;

            MyEventListener eventListener = new MyEventListener();

            pkgLocation =
              @"D:\Driver_Impact\Driver_Impact\Package.dtsx";
            app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, eventListener);
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute(null, null, eventListener, null, null);

            Console.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Tech Stack

Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT

SQL server 2016

Comment: Version 14 is targeting SQL Server 2017. Have you checked in the properties of your SSIS project > Configuration Properties > General > Deployment Target Version that the TargetServerVersion setting is "SQL Server 2016" or less?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I checked it is 2016

Comment: Which version of Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime is being referenced in the C# project?

Comment: It looks like you're writing your own execution framework for running SSIS packages. Be advised that unless this application runs on the machine that has a licensed copy of SQL Server on it, you'll run into technical issues as well as legal/licensing issues